# Gecko 45 c# winform add script to document

Tags: c#, gecko

I get error when i use void. Please help me

```
string output;
using (AutoJSContext jsContext = new AutoJSContext(wb.Window.JSContext))
{
       jsContext.EvaluateScript(jsStr, out output);
}
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Geckofx-Core.dll
>
> Additional information: JSContext don't store their default compartment object on the cx.

Answer (score 0):

Since Gecko 45, I use the other `EvaluateScript` overload to make it work :

```
  string output;
  using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(wb.Window))
  {
     context.EvaluateScript(jsStr, (nsISupports) wb.Window.DomWindow, out output);

  }
```